# C++ How to find the longest possible combination of decreasing numbers in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-tree, combinations

I am working on a problem in which I'm given a list of numbers representing the diameter of cake layers (for example: 9 12 10 7 4 6 11 5). With this list, I have to find the length of the longest combination of numbers that are equal to or decreasing (stacking cake layers from greatest diameter at the bottom to smallest at the top). You are allowed to skip over numbers, but you can't come back to them. I.e. with the previous list, the length of the longest combination would be 5 with the combination being (12,10,7,6,5).

I believe that the best way to solve this would be feeding the array into a tree and returning the height of the tree. This is currently the code I have, with a working tree implementation above the main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string sizeInput, transfer; //Strings to hold input and transfer to array

int maxLayers = 0, numOfInputs = 0, numNodes = 0; //ints for holding the max height and the number of inputs by the user
int cakeSizes [30]; //Array holding sizes of the cakes input, no more than 30

cout << "Cake sizes: ";
getline(cin,sizeInput); //Gets input from user and puts into a stringstream

stringstream readInput(sizeInput);
while(readInput >> transfer)
{
    cakeSizes[numOfInputs] = stoi(transfer); //Puts the numbers into the array and counts how many were placed
    numOfInputs++;
}

for(int i=0; i<numOfInputs; i++) //Puts the array into a tree
{
    Tree<int> cakeStack; //Creates tree to hold combination
    initialize(cakeStack);

    for(int j=i; j<numOfInputs; j++)
    {
        if(cakeSizes[j]<=cakeSizes[j-1])
        {
            insert(cakeStack, cakeSizes[j]);
        }
    }
    if(height(cakeStack) > maxLayers) //Checks if the new combination tree's height is greater than the last
    {
        maxLayers = height(cakeStack);
    }
    destroy(cakeStack); //Destroys the tree from the previous combination in preparation for new one
}

cout << endl << "You can build a cake with " << maxLayers << " layers.";
}
```

This actually works for combinations that are always decreasing (like 5,4,2,1 and 8,3,2,1), but it fails when interrupting numbers are thrown in (like with 5,4,2,8,1). I'm almost certain that the problem lies here:

```
for(int j=i; j<numOfInputs; j++)
    {
        if(cakeSizes[j]<=cakeSizes[j-1])
        {
            insert(cakeStack, cakeSizes[j]);
        }
    }
```

But I'm unsure of how to implement it an a way that checks all combinations of the array (like skipping numbers that wouldn't give the longest combination), rather than running straight down the list unable to skip numbers.

Comment: This is a well-known programming problem called 'longest decreasing subsequence'.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence

Answer (score 0):

The tree is definitely the way to go. You build the tree by inserting each value under the smallest node larger than it. Then when the tree is finished you iterate through it looking for the longest path.

What I did in the code below is I made a head node to store the sub trees and it needed a really large value so that all the inputs would fit under it.  But then when I print the tree or look for a path I need to ignore that head node, so I have to keep track of the depth.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>

struct Tree {
    Tree(int value) : value(value) {}
    int value;
    std::vector<Tree> children;
};

// Recursively check this level of the tree
void insert_node(Tree& node, int value)
{
    // if the new value is bigger than where
    // we are then stop descending
    if (value > node.value)
        return;

    // if the new value fits under this
    // parent then check all the children
    bool inserted = false;
    for (Tree& child : node.children)
        // if we find a child large enough
        // then insert ourselves inside
        if (value < child.value)
        {
            insert_node(child, value);
            inserted = true;
        }

    // if the new value fits under this parent but
    // not under any of the children then put it here
    if (!inserted)
        node.children.push_back(value);
}

void print_tree(Tree node,
                std::vector<bool> flags = std::vector<bool>(100, true),
                bool last = false,
                int depth = 0) 
{ 
    for (int i = 1; i < depth; ++i)
    {
        if (flags[i])
            std::cout << "|  ";
        else
            std::cout << "   ";
    }

    // Don't print our fake head
    if (depth > 0) 
    { 
        std::cout << "+- " << node.value << '\n'; 
        if (last) flags[depth] = false; 
    }

    int n = 0;
    for (Tree child : node.children)
    {
        last = (n++ == node.children.size() - 1);
        print_tree(child, flags, last, depth + 1);
    }
    
    flags[depth] = true; 
} 

void print_path(std::vector<int> path)
{
    std::cout << "Path:";
    for (int value : path)
        std::cout << " " << value;
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void print_paths(Tree node,
                 std::vector<int>& max_path,
                 std::vector<int> path = std::vector<int>(),
                 int depth = 0)
{
    // Don't add our fake head
    if (depth > 0)
        path.push_back(node.value);

    if (node.children.size() == 0)
    {
        print_path(path);
        
        // check if this path is the longest one yet
        if (max_path.size() < path.size())
            max_path = path;
    }
        
    for (Tree child : node.children)
        print_paths(child, max_path, path, depth + 1);
} 

int main()
{
    Tree head(INT_MAX);
    std::vector<int> input = {9, 12, 10, 7, 4, 6, 11, 5};

    // Build the tree
    for (int value : input)
        insert_node(head, value);

    // Print the tree
    std::cout << "Tree:\n";
    print_tree(head);
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Print the paths and
    // find the longest one
    // and then print it too
    std::vector<int> max_path;
    print_paths(head, max_path);
    std::cout << "\nLongest ";
    print_path(max_path);

    return 0;
}
```